# Visual Studio-like refactor tool for SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax, automated-refactoring

Are there any free tools providing snippets and syntax checking similar to Refactor in Visual Studio 2003/05/08/10?

@edit: To MSSQL, any version..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this:

[SSMS Tools](http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/Features?f=3)

It offers snippets, basic formatting and a bunch of other features.

Comment: @Filip, @Quickfire55; Although Both seemed useful, this is the one I'm more familiar with. Thank you both.

Answer (score 0):

The only tool I know about is [RedGate SQL Refactor](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-prompt/sql-refactor). I have tried it a number of times, but I always end up uninstalling because it's not good enough to my liking.

Answer (score 0):

You can try out free SSMS and VS add-in, [ApexSQL Complete](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_complete.aspx)

ApexSQL Complete provides snippets and syntax checking and a lot of other features (aliases, the Insert procedure parameters automatically option , the Insert full INSERT statement option and so on)

*Disclaimer: I work for ApexSQL as a Support Engineer*